# How to return list with negative integer in the program?

Tags: python

sum_of_n takes an integer n and returns a List of length abs(n) + 1. 
The List/Array contains the numbers in the arithmetic series produced by taking the sum of the consecutive integer numbers from 0 to n inclusive.

Example

5 -> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

-5 -> [0, -1, -3, -6, -10, -15]

7 -> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]

```
def sum_n(n):
    a=n+1
    x=0
    b=0
    list1=[]
    for x in  range(0,a): 
        b=(x*(x+1)*0.5)
        list1.append(int(b))
    return list1

print sum_n(5)
print sum_n(-5)
```

----output------

[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

[]

please explain me how can I return list with **negative** integer??

Comment: Why not `list1 = [ x*(x+1)//2 for x in range(a)]` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant as a replacement for the for loop, not "how do I get range to give me negative numbers".  It works fine in Python 3 for positive values.  For Python 2 you need / rather than //.  For negative values you need some of the other answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For negative integers, you need to use a negative step in your `range()`. So:

```
if a < 0:
    step = -1
else:
    step = 1
for x in range(0, a, step):
```

Now, in your calculation of `b`, you're adding `1` to `x`. This also needs to be changed to `-1` when doing negative numbers. So you can just throw `step` in where you had `1`.

Also, there's a difference between multiplying by 0.5 and dividing by 2 when dealing with negative numbers, and to get the result you're looking for you want the latter. So your calculation of `b` should now be:

```
b = x * (x + step) // 2
```

As a bonus, this will always be an integer, so you don't need the `int(b)` later (though it won't hurt).

Comment: You also need to calculate `b` as `x*(x+step)//2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not an issue with the return, but that your list is actually empty. Did you mean to take the absolute value of n before assigning it to a?

You could add a print statement in your loop to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if a < 0:
a = -5 #just defined the variable for easy explanation
y = 0
list1 = [0]
for x in range (1,abs(a)+1):
    for h in range(x+1):
        y -= h #<---- here
    list1.append(y)
    y = 0
print (list1)
```

Output

```
>>> 
[0, -1, -3, -6, -10, -15]
>>>
```

Just minest instead of sum.

Comment: def sum_of_n(n):
                  return [(-1 if n < 0 else 1) * sum(range(i+1)) for i in range(abs(n)+1)]